Moving object in an array in sync with UI
I recognise this question seems quite basic, but please do read on. I have read this question, which explains the results but not the solution.
Imagine you have a todo app, with 5 tasks:
var tasks = [
    "Go to the shops",
    "Grab a coffee with John",
    "Put on the washing machine",
    "Put clothes in dryer",
    "Fold and put away clothes"
]

And the user wants to be able to move tasks freely in the list.
For example, let's say they decide to go to the shops last, and want to move the item from position 0 (the first position), to position 4 (the current last index).
If you did tasks.move(fromOffsets: [0], toOffset: 4), you'd end up with:
[
    "Grab a coffee with John", 
    "Put on the washing machine", 
    "Put clothes in dryer", 
    "Go to the shops", 
    "Fold and put away clothes"
]

The item from position 0 is not in position 4 now.
Whereas I'd expect if I move something from 0 to 4, then print(tasks[4]), I should get what was in position 0.
Ok so let's say we offset this instead and say the user moves to n+1, where n is their destination index.
tasks.move(fromOffsets: [0], toOffset: 4 + 1)
print(tasks[4]) // "Go to the shops"

Ok, better, but this only works in one direction:
var tasks = [
    "Go to the shops",
    "Grab a coffee with John",
    "Put on the washing machine",
    "Put clothes in dryer",
    "Fold and put away clothes"
]


tasks.move(fromOffsets: [4], toOffset: 0 + 1)
print(tasks[0]) // "Go to the shops"

So, is the solution here:
If the user is moving to an index higher than the current:

Use n+1

if the user is moving to an index lower than the current:

Use n

Advice and solutions appreciated.

The point you seem to have overlooked in the other question and its answers is that toOffset is based on the existing offsets before anything is moved. So in your first example, your goal is to move to offset 5, not offset 4.

The documentation clearly states what toOffset means.

The offset of the element before which to insert the moved elements.

You wrote 4. At tasks[4] there is "Fold and put away clothes", so the elements are inserted before that.
The destination parameter for insert has the same semantics. You would not expect tasks.insert("New Element", at: 4) to insert the element at the end of the tasks array, would you?
The difference is that insert doesn't remove anything, so the new element always ends up at the index you specified.
You can think of move(fromOffsets:toOffset:) does the same insertion, but it also removes the thing originally at the indices in fromOffsets, shifting all the indices before toOffset as a result.
So your observation is correct for the case where fromOffsets has only one element.
In more general terms, to move n elements at indices { i_1 ... i_n } (where i_1 ... i_n are in ascending order), such that the element at i_1 ends up at index j, the argument to toOffset needs to be j + m, where m is the number of elements in the set { i_1 ... i_n } that is less than j.
